# Can you explain this code to me about "Recursion to Create a Range of Numbers"?

Tags: javascript, recursion

Can you explain this code to me about "Recursion to Create a Range of Numbers"?

```js
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
  if (endNum < startNum){
    return [];
  } else{
    var countArray = rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum -1);
    countArray.push(endNum);
    return countArray;
  }
  
};

console.log(rangeOfNumbers(1,20));
```

Answer (score 1):

Running the updated function below should create the output below - demonstrating how the array(s) are not really created until the recursion has reached max depth and starts to return...

```
start returning
[ 1 ]
[ 1, 2 ]
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

Explanation as comments in the code below...

```
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
    /* the line below checks to see if the end of the  
       recursion has been reached. If so, it starts returning. 
       The criteria is that the value of endNum, which 
       initially is bigger that startNum, has been 
       decremented until it has become less the startNum */
    if (endNum < startNum){
    /* the line below shows that no arrays are actually 
       created until the recursion has reached its max depth:
       the original value of endNum */    
       console.log('start returning') // debug 1
      return [];
    } else{
      /* as long as the endNum has not been reached,
         the function continues to call itself, digging
         deeper down into the stack.
         NB how the value of endNum is decremented by one
         before being handled by the next call to the 
         function: endNum - 1 */ 
      var countArray = rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum -1);
      /* it is not until the max depth has been reached,
         the two lines of code below kick into action - creating an 
         array counting backwards, making the 
         final value of endNum the first value in the
         array. Javascript's array push() method appends
         a value to the end of the array */ 
      countArray.push(endNum);
      /* the line below, displays each array created 
         at each step back up from the bottom depth of endNum */
        console.log(countArray) // debug 2 
      return countArray;
    }
    
  };

rangeOfNumbers(1,5);

//  console.log(rangeOfNumbers(1,5));
```